# JSON conversion issue from JS to Google Cloud Endpoints server

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

When executing the call I get a server exception:

```
var x = '{"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}}';
gapi.client.realestate.create(x).execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RpcApiServlet.doSingleBackendCall(RpcApiServlet.java:131)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RpcApiServlet.service(RpcApiServlet.java:112)
```

If I use the same JSON expression in `API Explorer`, it works. The `@ApiMethod` is defined as:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "create", path = "properties", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void create(RealEstateProperty property, User user) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JS Client library methods expect JSON objects and not JSON strings, it does the encoding for the call itself. Also since this is a POST request you will have to define the POST body as a `resource` parameter for the method (which isn't really well documented unfortunately)

This should work:

```
var x = {"name": "Test","address": { "street": "White House"}};
gapi.client.realestate.create({"resource": x}).execute( ...
```

Comment: I don't have the exception anymore but the `property` object on the server side is not populated. The instance is created but the fields are `null`.

Comment: @Sydney, have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988725/making-calls-from-the-javascript-client-library-with-named-and-unnamed-paramete).