# Making calls from the Javascript client library with @Named and unnamed parameters makes no sense

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-client

I have a `Cloud Endpoints` method that looks like this:

```
//HTTP POST
@ApiMethod(name = "hylyts.insert")
public Hylyt insertHylyt(@Named("url") String url, Hylyt hylyt, User user)
        throws OAuthRequestException{
    log.info("Trying to save hylyt '"+hylyt+"' with id '"+hylyt.getId());
    if (user== null) throw new OAuthRequestException("Your token is no good here.");
    hylyt.setArticle(getArticleKey(url, user));
    ofy().save().entity(hylyt);
    return hylyt;
}
```

I call it from the `Javascript Client Library` using this:

```
gapi.client.hylytit.hylyts.insert({PARAMS}).execute(callback);
```

Now, if I structure `{PARAMS}` as suggested in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#ExampleGoogleCloudStorage) (second example),

```
{
  'url': url,
  'resource': {
    'hylyt': {
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'data': hylyt
    }
  }
}
```

I get a null object in the endpoint (not to mention that the whole point of this library is to make these calls simple, which this structure clearly violates).

When I structure `{PARAMS}` as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458007/1720014) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804951/google-cloud-endpoints-making-calls-with-js-client-passing-params-and-json-bo/19809245#19809245) suggest,

```
{
  'url': url,
  'resource': hylyt
}
```

I get a null object in the endpoint again. The correct syntax is this:

```
{
  'url': url,
  'id': hylyt.id
  'text': hylyt.text
}
```

Which just blows my mind. Am I doing this all wrong? Is this a bug? Is it only happening because `gapi` is also passing the `auth token` in the background?

Yes, I could use the `request` syntax instead, but, again, why even use the library if it's just as complex as making the `XHR`s in pure javascript? I wouldn't mind the complexity if Google explained in the docs *why* things are happening. But the docs, paraphrased, just say use these methods and the auth, CORS, and XHR magic will happen behind closed doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been resolved. The correct syntax is

```
gapi.client.hylytit.hylyts.insert({url: url}, hylyt).execute(callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the API method correctly recognized as `POST` method?

The resource parameter which is sent as POST body won't work correctly in a `GET` request.
The way it looks you are actually sending a `GET` request with the Hylyt properties in the query string.

To make sure you can change the method annotation to this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "hylyts.insert", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
```

Comment: I double-checked the API discovery, and it's correctly identified as a `POST` method. If you look at the Tic Tac Toe sample, when they [insert](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/war/js/base.js) (line 138) a score, they actually pass the score.outcome, not the score object itself. Here's the [endpoint](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/src/com/google/devrel/samples/ttt/spi/ScoresV1.java). This is what made me try the structure that finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, agreed it's a bug. caused me great pains as well.

So i guess the work around is to create a combined object to pass to your api all named and un named parameters. Rather than hardcode each.. a quick loop might be better.

```
var param = {};
param["url"] = url;
for (var prop in hylyt) {
  param[prop] = hylyt[prop];
}
gapi.client.hylytit.hylyts.insert(param).execute(callback);
```

That mashing together of parameters / objects can become a slick function if you really want.. but it's a band aid for what I'd consider a defect.
I see in the related question ([cloud endpoints resource attribute for transmitting named params & body not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021241/cloud-endpoints-resource-attribute-for-transmitting-named-params-body-not-work)), you actually logged a defect.. Good stuff. Though there still appears no movement on this one. fingers crossed for someday!